# Redirect on the basis of referer HTTP_REFERER htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-referer

I've an issue where i want to redirect a user on the basis of a substring from referered url,  How i can accomplish that using htaccess?

1. User is on http://example.com/aqeel/videos/
2. There is a hyperlink on the above page http://demo.example.com/
3. When user reaches http://demo.example.com/, I want him to be redirected to http://demo.example.com/login/aqeel/, Here aqeel is the substring captured from the referer url in htaccess from step 1 URL.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code to make that work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http\:\/\/example.com/([a-z]+)/videos/
RewriteRule (.*)$ /login/%1/
```

I tried on my domain.. and it works... hope that too work with you... :)